# supervise (python deamontools) exits after closing ssh client

Tags: python, service, ssh

I am trying to keep a python script running on my server after I close my ssh client connection. Normally I use

```
sudo supervise . >output.log 2>err.log < /dev/null &
```

but now on a new server its not working. It works fine when i start it first and still connected but the second I close my connection supervise stops.
This is my run file, and I've tripled checked its in the correct directory:

```
#!/bin/bash         

sudo python3 Server.py
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For such task I use `screen`, that creates virtual terminals that can be safely detached.

You can find brief tutorial [here](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/a-quick-tutorial-on-screen/).